# edit select option values

Tags: php, forms, edit

I am trying to edit my form. I want to get selected value selected in selection list.

I have created function to store values in database, and it works. Below is html code I use and function below to insert values in database.

// insert values in database

```
<label>Dobavljač</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dobavljac" required>
<?php dobavljac() ?>
</select>

function dobavljac(){
$sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `partneri` WHERE `Dobavljac`='1'
order by `PartnerId` asc "); 
echo '<option value="">Izaberi dobavljača</option>';
    while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<option value= "' .$record['PartnerId']. '">' . $record['PartnerNaziv'] . ' </option>';
        }
}
```

// edit values
First I retrieve information from database

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM materijali where Id=$id ";
$q = $conn->query($sql);
$r = $q ->fetch();
if ($r) {
$dobavljac=$r['Dobavljac'];
```

I want to get selected value in box

```
<label>Dobavljač</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dobavljac" value="<?php echo $dobavljac; ?>">
<?php dobavljac() ?>
</select>
```

Probably I am not doing it the right way, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: well, if i'm right, your `$link` is missing in ur `dobavljac` function so mysqli_query will fire a warning if this isn't a valid mysqli ressource link

Comment: There's special attribute `selected` that used for `option`

Comment: I use $link but did not post here because it contains database information.

Comment: well then insert it but hide your access info lik `$link = mysqli_connect("HOST","USER","PASS","DB")` or simply x'n'out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<label>Dobavljač</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="dobavljac" value="<?php echo $dobavljac; selected?>">
    <option value=<?php echo $dobavljac?> selected>
    <?php dobavljac() ?>
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM materijali where Id=$id ";
$q = mysql_query($query);

echo "<select name="dobavljac" class="form-control">";
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($q)) != null)
{
    echo "<option value = '{$row['Dobavljac']}'>";
    echo $row['Dobavljac'];
    echo "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_` and your answer is `mysql_`.

Comment: ...meaning, those two different APIs do not mix together.